# Do I need to import X library, if it's imported within a Y module I'm importing in the current file?

Tags: python, import, module, libraries

For example, I have date_file.py:

```
import datetime

EPOCH = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)

def date_to_unix(dt):
    return (dt - EPOCH).total_seconds() * 1000.0
```

and I have utils.py:

```
import date_file

ux = date_file.date_to_unix(datetime.datetime(2020,3,27,0,0,0))

print(ux)
```

But when I run utils.py it says

> "name datetime is not defined"

Isn't it a bit redundant to import these modules everywhere? Is there a better solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you need to import the elements as well. What you did was just import the file itself, but not what is in it.

To import the elements you must use this line in your file utils.py

```
from date_file import *
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my question but now I have a new one: If I just `import datetime,data_file` (not from _ import *) I can still use the functions from that file. So what's exactly the difference between `import data_file` and `from data_file import *`? From what I undertand here the only difference is that with the latter you also import the modules imported in the first one? Thanks again!

Comment: This link: [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function] explains everything, but if you wanted you could use: ux = date_file.date_to_unix (date_file.datetime.datetime (2020,3,27,0,0,0)). It is not that import did not take everything. In fact everything in the import is in the variable you took. So if I have 'import a' and 'a' has the 'b' method, I can use a.b to use the method.